# Bulk ALTER table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lot of tables that all have the same naming logic:
tbl_xxxxx_Tijden where xxxxx is a number

I need to add an extra field to these tables, an INT type field.
So, I guess that would look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_xxxxx_Tijden ADD newfield INT
```

My question is: how to discard the xxxxx part and use

```
ALTER tablename like 'tbl_%_Tijden' ADD newfield INT
```

thanks,
James

Comment: Why do you "a lot of tables that all have the same naming logic: tbl_xxxxx_Tijden where xxxxx is a number"? Seems like a very odd database design.

Comment: Your options are dynamyc sql or udocumented sp_MSforeachtable http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx

Comment: jarlh, answering a question with an unrelated new question doesn't help anyone. The reason is well thought through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this is using dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'ALTER TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +' ADD newfield INT; '
FROM Information_schema.Tables
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_%_Tijden'

EXEC(SQL)
```

Comment: Just had to take out some small errors in your answer, but it was quick, and otherwise correct! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :-). The code was written directly here, so I'm not surprized you found errors. I've edited my answer to correct them so that this answer may proove useful for future readers.